# What is the shape of numpy array for tiff file?

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I'd like to make image with multi slices with .tiff extension. I heard that tiff can contain multiple images stacked.

So, I read multiple images(.png) with numpy array, which has shape (width, height, 3).
(3 : rgb channel)

Then, in order to stack 100 slices, what would be total shape of tiff file?
Would it  be (100, width, height, 3)? (width, height, 3, 100)? (width, height, 100, 3)? or any else?

Comment: Numpy uses row major order by default. Most commonly a (100, height, width, 3) image array would be stored in a TIFF file in 100 pages/IFDs with ImageLength=height, ImageWidth=width, and 3 contiguous SamplesPerPixel. TIFF has many options though.